# How to sort array by two different properties?

Tags: javascript, sorting, lodash

I'm trying to sort an array with lodash where I'm sorting by two properties. My current sort looks something like this but it's not working.

```
const sortedItems = orderBy(items, i => [i.Version,i.Active],['desc])
```

I want the sort to do this. From:

```
[{
    "Active": false,
    "Version": 1
  },
  {
    "Active": true,
    "Version": 3
  },
  {
    "Active": true,
    "Version": 2
  },
  {
    "Active": false,
    "Version": 1
  },
  {
    "Active": false,
    "Version": 4
  },
  {
    "Active": true,
    "Version": 5
  },
  {
    "Active": false,
    "Version": 1
  }
]
```

and sort it like this ..

```
[
    {
        "Active": true,
        "Version": 5
      },
    {
        "Active": true,
        "Version": 3
      },
    {
      "Active": true,
      "Version": 2
    },
    {
        "Active": false,
        "Version": 4
      },

    {
      "Active": false,
      "Version": 1
    },
    {
      "Active": false,
      "Version": 1
    },

    {
      "Active": false,
      "Version": 1
    }
  ]
```

Is there another lodash function that does this for me or do I need to use two functions separately?

Comment: Why don't you just use the `sort` function for arrays?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var data = [{
    "Active": false,
    "Version": 1
  },
  {
    "Active": true,
    "Version": 3
  },
  {
    "Active": true,
    "Version": 2
  },
  {
    "Active": false,
    "Version": 1
  },
  {
    "Active": false,
    "Version": 4
  },
  {
    "Active": true,
    "Version": 5
  },
  {
    "Active": false,
    "Version": 1
  }
];


console.log(
  data.sort((a, b) => (b.Active - a.Active || b.Version - a.Version))
);
```

- b - a will make it sort descending
- If b.Active and a.Active are not equal, it will short circuit and give precedence to the Active property
- If b.Active and a.Active are equal, it will continue on to sort descending by the sub-precedence Version

Answer (score 2):

You can do it in using JS array sort method. Just write a compare function according to your condition and use that function inside JavaScript array sort method when sorting.

```js
const data = [
  {
    Active: false,
    Version: 1,
  },
  {
    Active: true,
    Version: 3,
  },
  {
    Active: true,
    Version: 2,
  },
  {
    Active: false,
    Version: 1,
  },
  {
    Active: false,
    Version: 4,
  },
  {
    Active: true,
    Version: 5,
  },
  {
    Active: false,
    Version: 1,
  },
];

const cmp = (x, y) => {
  if (x.Active === y.Active) {
    return y.Version - x.Version;
  }
  return x.Active < y.Active ? 1 : -1;
};
const ret = data.sort(cmp);
console.log(ret);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the method sort of vanilla JavaScript

```
let not_sorted = {[]};
let sorted = not_sorted.sort(sorter);

function sorter(a,b)
{
   if(a.Version>b.Version)
    {
      return -1;
    }
    else{
      return 1;
    }
}
```

It should work (you can change the order just changing values of return)